# eclipse helios tomcat error

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I just created a struts application in eclipse Helios. when I run as server I get an alert like this. My browser is online only.

> This document cannot be displayed
>   while offline. To go online, uncheck
>   Work Offline from the File menu.

and this is error displayed.

> Dec 23, 2010 7:20:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
>   SEVERE: An incompatible version 1.1.15 of the APR based Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version 1.1.17 
>   Dec 23, 2010 7:20:37 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
>   WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:StrutsHelloWorld' did not find a matching property.
>   Dec 23, 2010 7:20:37 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
>   INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
>   Dec 23, 2010 7:20:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
>   INFO: Initialization processed in 1081 ms
>   Dec 23, 2010 7:20:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
>   INFO: Starting service Catalina
>   Dec 23, 2010 7:20:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
>   INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.29
>   Dec 23, 2010 7:20:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
>   SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FileDispatcher
>    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1645)
>    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1491)
>    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:269)
>    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
>    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
>    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4001)
>    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4651)
>    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
>    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
>    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
>    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
>    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
>    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
>    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
>    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
>   Dec 23, 2010 7:20:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
>   SEVERE: Error filterStart
>   Dec 23, 2010 7:20:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
>   SEVERE: Context [/StrutsHelloWorld] startup failed due to previous errors

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore the browser message and look at the stacktrace - `Exception starting filter struts2 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FileDispatcher`.

The web application has not started.  Once this is fixed, then see if the browser displays the same message.